# only static members can be accessed in initializers flutter while passing data from one screen to another screen

Tags: flutter

Note: both are stateful widgets

I am trying to pass data from screen_1 to screen_2
and trying to make an API hit...

But while crafting **Dynamic URL** I am facing an issue which is

**SCREEN - 1**

```
Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: ((context) =>
           courseDetailScreen(
           color1: color[index][0],
           color2: color[index][1],
           title: myData[index]["title"],
           ind: index,
        )),
));
```

**SCREEN - 2**

[image]

Comment: check out my answer. @Chirag Chopra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the error by initializing your URL in your `getData()` function.
Like the code below:

```
Future<String> getJson() async{
    // initialize the url in the getdata funcion to avaoid the error
  final String url = 'http://dummy.herokuapp.com/courseModuleScreen/en' + ind.toString();

  var response = await http.get(
    /// the rest of your code here
  )
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Clad it helped. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer so others can see the relevance. @ChiragChopra